# agent.exe / Macrovision Software Manager Agent eats CPU

Tags: windows-xp

agent.exe process (with the description "Macrovision Software Manager Agent") needs 30-50% CPU usage. After killing the process, it starts again some seconds later.

My virus scanner (OfficeScan) does not report any viruses.

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

The program you're referring to is part of the InstallShield Update Service Agent which is a Windows process created by Macrovision Software Manager Agent. It can connect to the Internet in the background and check for updates to various software titles you have installed. To prevent it from doing so:

1. Open Control panel and double click the Software Manager icon.
2. Goto settings, click the the name of any software from the list and select "Check for updates manually" – Do an apply all.